# Reenvió de un post mediante formato JSON C# Console Application

Tags: c#

Actualmente envió un post a una url mediante una aplicación de consola en C# pero el detalle esta en que si el servidor no esta disponible, la información  se pierde y no he encontrado la manera de como realizar un (N) reenvío de esa información. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Esta es la forma en como envió la información a una url:

```
string url = "http://186.174.220.249/publico/pd.aspx?id=" 
String paramsPost = {"Dato",  "Dato"};
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpRequest.Method = "POST"; 
httpRequest.ContentLength = paramsPost.Length;
Stream stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(paramsPost), 0, paramsPost.Length);
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de como hacer un reenvío?
saludos y Gracias

Comment: A ver, vamos por partes: primero bienvenido a SOes, segundo, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que puedas ver el funcionamiento del sitio a un mayor detalle (de paso que obtienes la primera medalla). Ahora bien, aquí tenemos un problema que se escapa a las manos pues es de un servidor donde no se tiene acceso, lo que queda es verificar si la URL está disponible mediante un simple get en un intervalo de tiempo, de lo contrario, ejecutas nuevamente el envío y esperas resultado, personalmente te recomiendo que a lo mucho debes intentar 5 veces para que exista respuesta. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que ponerlo dentro de un `while` y preguntar siempre si la peticion fue exitosia. Si no lo fue, pues que se ejecute otra vez:

```
while(true)
{

  string url = "http://186.174.220.249/publico/pd.aspx?id=" 
  String paramsPost = {"Dato",  "Dato"};
  HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  httpRequest.Method = "POST"; 
  httpRequest.ContentLength = paramsPost.Length;
  Stream stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
  stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(paramsPost), 0, paramsPost.Length);
  var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
  stream.Flush();
  stream.Close();
  var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

   // si el estatus code fue 200(ok) pues entonces sal del bluque 
  if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
  {
    break;
  }
   // de lo contrario no saldra el buque e intentara cuantas veces sea necesario.

  Thread.Sleep(3000); // le damos 3 segundos para ejecutar la peticion otra vez en caso de que el server vuelva.
}
```